Java , firebase-admin module not found
I've just created new java 17 project with gradle 8.5 build system.
added admin sdk dependecy in build.gradle.
Synced project. Dependecy was downloaded. But after i was tried to run main module with Firebase app initialization i've got that error:
error: module not found: firebase.admin
    requires firebase.admin;
                     ^

My build.gradle :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'com.lifedrained'
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.3.0'
}

test {
}

My module-info.java:
module main{
    requires firebase.admin;
}

I can't even imagine why it can't find firebase.admin module. For an example: if i  add apache commons io library in module info it finds apache commons io module without problems. My IntellIJ  perfectly see firebase admin module 
